# Paint event sequence

Tags: c#, winforms

I run the program from `Form3`. Why does the program execute `Picture1_Paint` of `Form3` first instead `Picture1_Paint` of `Form1`, how to change the sequence?

```
private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ss = new Form1();
    ss.Show();  // Here Form1 is loaded, but its Picture1_paint is not executed

    FootingWidth.Text = ss.richTextBox9.Text; 

    pictureBox1.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.pictureBox1_Paint);

    pictureBox1.Refresh();               
}

private void Form1_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    richTextBox1.Text = 1.0.ToString();
    richTextBox2.Text = 0.403.ToString();
    richTextBox3.Text = 0.0.ToString();

    pictureBox1.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.pictureBox1_Paint);

    pictureBox1.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: I need some data from Form1_Load event for Form3 so I want Picture1_paint of Form1 to be executed first.

Comment: Change Form1 to implement a new event, for example `AfterPictureBox1Paint`, and fire it at the end of the pictureBox1.Paint handler.  Change Form3 to subscribe to this new event instead of the pictureBox1.Paint event.

Answer (score 2):

The Form.Show() call only *starts* the process of making the window visible.  You cannot actually see it until your method completes and execution re-enters the message loop.  After which the Paint event is delivered if nothing else of importance needs to be done.  Painting order is back-to-front.

You *forced* the pictureBox1's Paint event to run by calling Refresh().  That isn't necessary, it will get the Paint event automatically.  But the code will certainly always get the pb's Paint event to run before any other.  Just remove the Refresh() call.

If there's any reason to force a paint to occur then use the Invalidate() method to tell Windows that the window ought to be repainted.  You can use the Update() method to force the Paint event to be delivered immediately.